# How to update asp.net azure application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I am new to windows azure. I've created simple HelloWorld ASP.NET azure application and published it. I know I can republish whole application in Visual Studio by clicking right button on project and then publish it. But is it possible to update only one file (aspx page, picture etc.)

Thanks!
Regards, Alexander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you're just learning Windows Azure, the most helpful answer is "You can't." The way Windows Azure works is that to update an application, you create the full package and deploy it again.

This isn't to say that David's answer isn't also correct. I just wanted to directly answer the question of "How do I change just one file after I deploy?"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update individual files such as images, one thing you can do is store all images (and css, javascript, and any other static content) in Blob storage. This has several advantages:

- Easy to upload new files individually, with both free tools and paid tools. For instance: [Cloudberry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx) is a free app, and Cerebrata [Cloud Storage Studio](http://cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/) is a paid app, both which let you manage containers and blobs individually.
- Smaller deployment package, because you've removed images and other large files
- Less load on IIS, since image requests go directly to blob storage, not to your role instances

You can't store your aspx files in blobs, though you can store static content like html in blobs. To update aspx, you're basically updating the deployment. You can now do this as an "upgrade" which doesn't disrupt your IP address and, if you have multiple instances, doesn't take down your service during upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me what is "upgrade"?

Comment: When you publish, you either "delete and redeploy" or "upgrade." In the former, you'd lose your IP address as everything is torn down and rebuilt. In the latter, the new deployment package replaces the old one, while leaving your deployment in place. If you have 2 or more instances, the upgrade is done in such a way that at least one instance remains running while others are being upgraded to the new code you pushed up.

Comment: Also: look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx), that shows what can be done in an upgrade without needing a delete+redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [webdeploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683672.aspx#EnableWebDeploy) (which should do a selective [update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683672.aspx#UpdateWebDeploy) of all files) or connect via [remote desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx) and update certain files yourself.
Like the comment and MSDN says: neither of these two ways are recommended/usable for production deployments. They are only meant as a shortcut for certain development scenarios.

Comment: Please, do NOT update via RDP. The moment your role instances have an issue (e.g. local disk gets moved, or you're moved to another box due to hardware issues), your changes are gone.